# Data not inserted using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm trying to insert data using SQLiteOpenHelper in my Current App.

When I am trying to run the app and entering the details, the toast says

> Data Not Inserted

Even I can't see my table in Android Device Monitor -> File Explorer
I can't see any folder under data directory.

**Here's my code:**

**DB_check.java**

```
package com.example.shubbh.qversoft_1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.shubbh.qversoft_1.Database.DatabaseHelper;

public class DB_check extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText EtCompanyName;
    Button bAdd, bReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_db_check);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        EtCompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.companyNameEt);
        bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBt);
        bReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetBt);
        bReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EtCompanyName.setText("");
            }
        });

        addData();
    }

    public void addData()
    {
        bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(EtCompanyName.getText().toString());

                if(isInserted == true)
                    Toast.makeText(DB_check.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(DB_check.this, "Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.shubbh.qversoft_1.Database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Shubbh on 8/1/2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Qversoft.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="CompanyName";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="Company_Name";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Company_Name TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String companyName)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, companyName);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1)
            return false;

        else return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_db_check.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shubbh.qversoft_1.DB_check">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/companyEt"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/companyNameEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:hint="Please Enter the Company Name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColorHint="#3b52c6"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:textColor="#f00" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<!--<EditText
    android:id="@+id/companyNameEt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:hint="Enter company name"/>-->


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/companyEt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addBt"
            android:layout_below="@id/companyNameEt"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetBt"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/companyEt"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/searchTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in logcat? If yes could you upload that too,

Comment: Uninstall the app or delete the app's data in case you have a buggy database already setup from previus runs. Re-run your app and see in the Android Studio Monitor if there is any Error. If yes please post the stack trace.

Comment: @juan Thanks, it worked !!  But will there be a problem again if I reinstall this app in my mobile?

Comment: Check my answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try again with replacing This.

//Careful of space.
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "("+COL_1 +" integer primary key autoincrement,"+COL_2+" text)");

   // And I have changed your insert method lil bit & added get Method:

    public void insertData(String companyName)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COL_2, companyName);
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        }

        public Cursor getData(){
            SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from CompanyName",null);
            return c;
        }

   // And inside on ClickListner of Add Button,

     myDb.insertData(EtCompanyName.getText().toString());

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Cursor c=myDb.getData();
                    if(c.moveToFirst()){
                        do{
                            String c_name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Company_Name"));
                            Log.d("Company_Name ::: ",c_name);
                        }while (c.moveToNext());
                    }

    Try To run Again.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the database doesn't get replaced when you install a new version of the app.

If during development you run tests or make changes to the database which lead to an inconsisten state (based on the new code you deploy), you will have unexpected results as it happens here.

The way to correct it in development is to delete the old data of the app (or remove the app and reinstall it).

When you go to production, it may happen that you have to apply changes to the database structure. When your users update their version, the database will not be reinstalled (they will still have the old version). That is why the DatabaseHelper class has the onUpgrade method.

By passing a new version number to the database helper class, that method gets executed and it is there where you have to provide the code for updating the old database to the new one transparently to the user.

Does this also answer:

> But will there be a problem again if I reinstall this app in my mobile?